# Creating a a range within a databodyrange

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub that updates a graph with the series based within a table. However, the first row of the table is blank and I want to omit that from my series collection. I thought of creating a range within my databody range and use that. This is my code:

```
Sub UpdateGraph()

Dim rng_pf As Variant, rng_bm As Variant, rng_date As Variant,
Dim lr as integer

' Defining ranges
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Time series")
         lr = .ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).Range.Rows.Count + 6 ' This corresponds to the last row in my table
         rng_pf = .ListObjects(1).ListColumns("PF").DataBodyRange(2, lr) ' <-- This doesnt work
         rng_bm = .ListObjects(1).ListColumns("BM").DataBodyRange(2, lr)
         rng_date = .ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Date").DataBodyRange(2, lr)
End With

' Updating chart
With Sheets(1).ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = rng_pf
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = rng_bm
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = rng_date
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = rng_date
End With

End sub
```

I thought of creating an array that is based on the databodyrange and then removing the first element of the array, but that seems to be overkill.
When running my code I get that rng_pf is `Empty`.
My table:
[image]

Comment: Is `Sheets("Time series")` the same as `Sheets(1)` ? I prefer to use the names, is less confusing and easier to debug.

Comment: It isn't the same and I cannot guarantee that it will have the same position in the workbook in the future. It comes from an external source. The figure is presented in sheet(1) always.

Comment: _I thought of creating an array that is based on the databodyrange and then removing the first element of the array, but that seems to be overkill._ - If you are building a stable application there is no such thing as overkill.  Build structured, well-documented code always.  It will save you time in the long run!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define ranges a bit better, but meanwhile give this a try?

````vb
Sub UpdateGraph()

Dim rng_pf As Range, rng_bm As Range, rng_date As Range

' Defining ranges
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Time series")
        With .ListObjects(1)
            With .ListColumns("PF")
                Set rng_pf = .DataBodyRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
            End With
            With .ListColumns("BM")
                Set rng_bm = .DataBodyRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
            End With
            With .ListColumns("Date")
                Set rng_date = .DataBodyRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
            End With
        End With
End With

' Updating chart
With Sheets(1).ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = rng_pf
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = rng_bm
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = rng_date
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = rng_date
End With

End Sub
```vba

**EDIT:** minor code cleanup as per OP suggestion.
````

Comment: That was my original code before I found the issue. Originally I defined them as ranges and did not specify a range within my databodyrange. This does mess up my graph as the first value in my ranges is empty, hence my problem.

Comment: Without specifying a range for DataBodyRange (which if i do, seems to be messing the chart), rng_pf and others have the right range... (2 to last row). all rng_pf is full, no empty values... where you get empty value? in the chart itself?

Comment: Added picture of the listobject. I could just remove the first row, but I prefer not messing with the original date.

Comment: Ah... missed the fact you are trying to get rid of the first row under the header... oh well. Let's rethink this.

Comment: It is perfect! Just fyi you duplicated the name of ranges in your solution.

Comment: Copy/Paste fail... I`ll correct the answer, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194122/discussion-between-blackbear-and-darxyde).

Comment: @BlackBear I feel bad for not having done that in the first place... oh well, done :)